# Overlapping rows with html/css

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

What would be the best and most clean way to do this layout with html/css?

[image]

What I have so far is https://codepen.io/sigug/pen/VxWJoJ
But that is 1) convoluted / not "clean" and 2) doesn't really work because it already looks different here than on codepen.
Thanks for any help..

```css
body { background: #ff00c6; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }

#icons { margin: auto auto; height: 10vh; border: 1px solid white; text-align: center; }
.icon {
  float: left;
}

.small { width: 1vw; p}

.large { width: 2vw; }
```

```html
<div id="icons">
  
<div class="icon" style="position: relative; left: 85px; top: -10px; "><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="small"></div>

<div class="icon" style="position: relative; left: 105px; top: -10px; "><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="small"></div>

<div class="icon" style="position: relative; left: 125px; top: -10px;"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="small"></div>
  
<div class="icon"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="large"></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="large"></div>
  <div class="icon"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png" class="large"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your code extensible and readable, so if you later want to add for example more rows, you easily can, by only changing the HTML markup. Maybe my solution is not 100% accurate, but I'll try to give you an idea on how to implement this layout.

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].style.transform='translate(0,-' + i + 'vw)';
}
```

```css
body {background:#ff00c6;width:100vw;height:100vh;}
#icons {border:1px solid white;}
.icon {float:left;width:2vw;height:2vw;background:url('https://image.ibb.co/jDaNTn/icon_notice.png') center center no-repeat;background-size:contain;}
.row {width:100%;height:2vw;}
.small .icon {background-size:50%}
.small .icon:first-child {margin-left:1vw;}

/* EDIT: JS solution
.row:nth-child(2) {transform:translate(0,-1vw);}
.row:nth-child(3) {transform:translate(0,-2vw);}
... */
```

```html
<div id="icons">
  <div class="small row">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="big row">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small row">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

> Edited the post, using transforms you can get the desired effect.
>   However this way you need to edit the CSS as well, because you need to
>   add some more translation to each row (-1vw, -2vw, -3vw, and so
>   on...). It's maybe better to calculate these with javascript or php.

Provided JS solution

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But how would the "overlapping" work now? This way it would be separated rows, but the small icons should be "between" the big ones (like screenshot)?

Comment: Edited the post, using transforms you can get the desired effect. However this way you need to edit the CSS as well, because you need to add some more translation to each row (-1vw, -2vw, -3vw, and so on...). It's maybe better to calculate these with javascript or php.